# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client v15 versus v16

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding

I'm working on an app to provision design elements to SharePoint Online. My project is relying on extension methods in [OfficeDevPnPCore](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP). This library references `v16` of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`. I need to `AlternateCssUrl` and `SiteLogoUrl`. These are fairly new (2014 April CU, according to a comment in PnP) and the recommended way to perform branding in SPO, as far as I understand. But I can only find these methods in `v15` of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client. The problem is that if I reference v15 in my project, I can't compile it, since it also includes a reference to OfficeDevPnPCore and v16. How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version (`16.0.3104.1200`) of [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038) available for download currently, `Web` object exposes `AlternateCssUrl` and `SiteLogoUrl` properties:

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
     var web = context.Web;
     web.AlternateCssUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/contoso.css";
     web.SiteLogoUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/SiteAssets/99x.png";
     web.Update();
     web.Context.ExecuteQuery();    
}
```

Comment: Vadim: do you by any chance know if and which CU for on-premises contains the required REST API changes to make the above code work for SP on-premises installations? TIA!

Comment: Sig, it seems it was added in 2014 April CU for on-premises,  https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Branding.AlternateCSSAndSiteLogo

Comment: Thanks Vadim. FYIO: the link you pointed me to mentions a June 30th 2014 release date. Couldn't find it when I asked in August, though https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113238/setting-spweb-alternatecssurl-via-csom-or-js

Comment: Oh, I did not know there was a separate SDK for SharePoint Online. I had already updated the normal one, but missed this one. Installing it solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't have the v16 DLLs on your system, or you have an old version.  If so, delete and re-install the [Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

They change fairly frequently so if things start breaking or failing to compile check for a new version.